# Inter-Server Communication

Tags: django, nginx

I have an Django application which uses different Servers.

-> First I get request, I need to authenticate it to my Authentication Server

-> Dump the request data in Log Server

-> Process the Request and getting data from different Database Server

-> Respond to the Request

-> Dump the Response data to Log Server

Each of the Server (Authentication Server, Log server...) are basically Django Services.

**What is the Best way to do this communication. Obviously HTTP Requests & Responses would take too long. Serving one Request would generate more than 5-6 new HTTP requests and responses.**

Can I have any way (applicable to Django) to directly call a method of other server (say Authentication Server, Log Server)

Comment: "Obviously" this would take too long? Have you measured it?

Comment: Have you looked at xml-rpc or something like this?

Comment: And you will have scale problems if you will **directly** call other server's method. In other words, you will just loose benefits of splitting application into services.

Comment: I want to add big chunks of (JSON) data to my Logs (Log server)